# Google amp page: how to add close button to amp-image-lightbox?

Tags: php, html, amp-html

How to add close button to `amp-image-lightbox`? Its closed by clicking outside of image, but what should be if aspect ratio match display? Code piece follow:

```
$rnd = rand(10000,20000);
$res = '<amp-img on="tap:lightbox'.$rnd.'" role="button" tabindex="0" src="'.$src[1].'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" layout="intrinsic" '.$style.'></amp-img>';
$res.= '<amp-image-lightbox id="lightbox'.$rnd.'" layout="nodisplay"></amp-image-lightbox>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes in your code :

```
$rnd = rand(10000,20000);
$res = '<amp-img on="tap:lightbox'.$rnd.'" role="button" tabindex="0" src="'.$src[1].'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" layout="intrinsic" '.$style.'></amp-img>';
$res.= '<amp-image-lightbox id="lightbox'.$rnd.'" layout="nodisplay"> <span on="tap:lightbox.close" role="button" tabindex="0">X</span></amp-image-lightbox>';
```

Example : [click here](https://codepen.io/bachchasingh/pen/WmQQjr)

```html
<!--
## Introduction

An AMP HTML tutorial - learn the different building blocks of an AMP HTML file. AMP HTML is entirely built on existing web technologies. It achieves reliable performance by restricting some parts of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. To make up for those limitations AMP HTML defines a set of custom elements for rich content beyond basic HTML. This samples shows what's necessary to create a valid AMP HTML file.
-->
<!-- -->
<!-- Doctype declaration is required. -->
<!doctype html>
<!-- This tells everyone that this is an AMP file. `<html amp>` works too. -->
<html ⚡>
<!-- ## Head -->
<!-- -->
<head>
  <!-- The charset definition must be the first child of the `<head>` tag. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> amp-image-lightbox</title>
  <!-- The AMP runtime must be loaded as the second child of the `<head>` tag.-->
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-image-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-image-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>
  <!--
    AMP HTML files require a canonical link pointing to the regular HTML. If no HTML version exists, it should point to itself.
  -->
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://ampbyexample.com/introduction/hello_world/">
  <!--
    AMP HTML files require a viewport declaration. It's recommended to include initial-scale=1.
  -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <!--
    CSS must be embedded inline.
  -->
  <style amp-custom>
    .close-button { position:fixed; top:50px; right:50%; transform:translateX(50%); z-index:1000; border:5px solid yellow; border-radius:10px; padding:2px;}
  </style>
  <!--
    The AMP boilerplate.
  -->
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
</head>
<!-- ## Body -->
<!-- -->
<body>
<h1>Add Custom Close Button In amp-image-lightbox</h1>

<amp-img on="tap:lightbox"
  role="button"
  tabindex="0"
  src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/9d0000/fff/&text=amp-image-lightbox"
  alt="Picture of a dog"
  title="Picture of a dog, view in lightbox"
  layout="responsive"
  width="300"
  height="246"></amp-img>
<amp-image-lightbox id="lightbox"
  layout="nodisplay">
  <span class="close-button" on="tap:lightbox.close" role="button" tabindex="0">X</span>
  </amp-image-lightbox>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, also for example to style it.

Answer (score 0):

Without html code, just CSS.
Put this on your styles:

For amp-image-lightbox:

```
#lightbox1::before {
  content:"X";
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
  right:19px;
  top:8px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  text-align:right;
  color:#fff;
}
```

The selector is the default example selector. Be sure it's correct.

On amp-lightbox:

```
.lightbox::before {
  content:"X";
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
  right:19px;
  top:8px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  text-align:right;
 color:#fff;
}
```

[Try it on codepen](https://codepen.io/gtamborero/pen/RwWJVdW)

Comment: The question was about amp-image-lightbox and you wrote solutions for amp-lightbox. These are different components.